# Http POST request with Windows CE

Tags: c#, http, windows-ce

Hey I'm trying to make a POST request with multiple parameters to finish part of the authentication process for my app. I'm not sure how to make this request I was looking through the documentation but couldn't find anything like `HttpWebRequest`. I'm not sure if I'm just missing a reference or if there is another way that i would have to go about this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it for anyone who was interested. If I added `using System.Net;` to my code `HttpWebRequest` became available.